# Left Join with no NA's generated

Tags: r

Say I have two dataframes:

```
a <- data.frame(id = 1:5, nom = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
b <- data.frame(id = 3:1, nom = c("C", "B", "A"))
```

and i would like to join the two dataframes such that it still has two columns (`id` and `nom`) but where `id = 4` and `id = 5`   the `nom` column retains the `d` and `e` values respectively. How do I achieve this? the solution I'd like looks like this:

[image]

Essentially, I'd like to avoid the NA output and retain the old rows where a left join match does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for adding output. From the link, you can do: `library(data.table); setDT(a); setDT(b); a[b, on=.(id), nom := i.nom][]`. I'll see if I can find other relevant links.